# How do you combine multiple meshes into one in Blender?

Tags: blender, 3d-meshes

I need to combine multiple meshes into one in Blender 2.8 (Just make them into a single mesh that looks like all of them in their normal positions). I am doing this mostly for performance improvement in my game, since the teeth are all separate.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Havent used blender in a while but if you just need to join the objects then sure you can, see this answer on [blender.se](https://blender.stackexchange.com): [How do I make multiple Blender objects into one?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2632/how-do-i-make-multiple-blender-objects-into-one#2633)

If you want to do other kinds of joining you might have a look into booltool for blender or join the objects first and then edit the resulting object yourself.